# Can I set a custom license using WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

The default license for an MSI generated by WiX is the common public license. How do I change this to GPLv2?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [WixVariable](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_wixvariable.htm) [XML element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Key_terminology) can be used.

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="path\License.rtf" />
```

And here's a few others...

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="path\banner.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="path\dialog.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIExclamationIco" Value="path\exclamation.ico" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIInfoIco" Value="path\information.ico" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUINewIco" Value="path\new.ico" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIUpIco" Value="path\up.ico" />
```

Just a note about the GPLv2. Officially it's only available in TXT; when converted to [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) using something like [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad), the hard coded new lines make for an untidy view in the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer).

Comment: Didn't state where to put it. The docs are similarly silent on the subject.

Answer (score 6):

Also worth mentioning is that you can provide variables on the command line, very handy when building localized MSI packages.

Example NANT code:

```
<light out="setup_${language}.msi"
  extensions="WixUIExtension"
  cultures="${language}" >

  <arg line="-loc &quot;setup-${language}.wxl&quot;" />
  <arg line="-dWixUILicenseRtf=EULA_${language}.rtf" />

  <!-- etc... -->

</light>
```

Comment: Nice! I'll have to try this. I assume these arguments will work with...

light foo=bar

... for example.

Comment: Don't forget the -d, e.g. "light -dfoo=bar"