# Where do I set the license text in Visual Studio 2008 Setup project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, wix

When I run the Output of my Visual Studio 2008 Setup project (`*.wixproj`), the install wizard displays a license.

Where do I change the text displayed? I have searched all `*.wxs` files, but cannot find the license displayed.

Also, a hint on where to find information on this stuff would be really cool...

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116228/can-i-set-a-custom-license-using-wix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add license.rtf file to wix project
and add

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="license.rtf">
```

in your Product tag